# ArrayList not being saved in database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to save a list item permanently on being upgraded. I have two activities - `MainActivity.java` and `Main2Activity.java`(EditText Activity) and a `DatabaseOperations` class. When I edit the example note, it gets updated in the `MainActivity.java`. However on closing the app and opening it again, the note reverts back to its former state and isn't saved.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView notesListView;
static ArrayList<String> notesArrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesListView);
    notesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    notesArrayList.add("Akhilesh Chobey");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notesArrayList);
    notesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    notesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("notePosition", i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Main2Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {

DatabaseOperations myDB;
EditText editNote;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    editNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);

    myDb = new DatabaseOperations(Main2Activity.this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getIntExtra("notePosition", -1);
    if(position != -1){

    editNote.setText(MainActivity.notesArrayList.get(position));

}
editNote.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if (myDb != null){ 
    boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData(editNote.getText().toString());
        if(isInserted){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        MainActivity.notesArrayList.set(position, String.valueOf(charSequence));
        MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - NullPointerException: storage == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939760/android-nullpointerexception-storage-null)

Comment: Are you getting the toast "Inserted" while editing the note from Main2Activity??

Comment: @sJy Yes I am getting the 'Inserted' toast

Answer (score 0):

Well you got a typo in there your only saving into your database is null `if (myDB == null)` change that to `if (myDB != null)`. Otherwise the code saving it to the DB wont be executed.

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity, you are always creating a new ArrayList with value "**Akhilesh Chobey**". This value is passed every time to your Main2Activity & getting set to the EditText.

**Solution** - In MainActivity, before adding "Akhilesh Chobey", check whether there is any existing data in DB. If data is present, add that to the arraylist OR if not present add "Akhilesh Chobey".

Comment: see the insertData code in onTextChanged listener. So I think, every time It won't insert the same  value "Akhilesh Chobey:. Right?

Comment: editNote.setText(MainActivity.notesArrayList.get(position)) will call onTextChanged listener.

Comment: It just called only during onCreate. But it will get called every time for every keyboard action.

Comment: You haven't written any code to fetch existing data from DB. What the code is doing is writing to DB only. Fetch the existing data & set it to the EditText in OnCreate().

Comment: Set it to EditText or to the ArrayList? But anyhow I am updating the ArrayAdapter. So what is going wrong?

Comment: In MainActivity, before adding "Akhilesh Chobey", check whether there is any existing data in DB. If data is present, add that to the arraylist OR if not present add "Akhilesh Chobey".

Comment: But data will always exist. How do I check that? Should I make the `myDb` static?